# Power Query Editor - Edit multiple columns with different values based on multiple conditions

Tags: multiple-columns, powerquery, multiple-conditions

I am using Power Query Editor and need to change several columns based on a  several conditions.

At the moment I am doing this in 3 separate steps using Table.ReplaceValue, but with each iterative step the variables in the conditions will change (because the first step is CommentCOPY = Comment, and I am relying on the other actions only happening when CommentCOPY = ""), therefore I need to do all 3 actions based on the first state (or to put it another way, 3 actions based on a single set of conditions).

I also only want the entire thing to run if a certain condition is true.

In my mind I want to do something like:

```
if Scope = "A" then
if ActionNeeded ^="" and CommentCOPY ="" then do;
   CommentCOPY = Comment;
   Action = ActionNeeded;
   AssignedTo = "Manager";
   end;
;
```

But I need power query code. Here is the initial table:

| AssignedTo | CommentCOPY | Action | ActionNeeded | Comment | Scope |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 |  |  | 1 | Do it now | A |
| User1 |  |  | 2 | Do it soon | A |
| User2 |  |  |  | Do it soon | A |
| User2 |  |  | 3 | Do it whenever | A |
| User3 |  |  | 1 | Do it now | A |
| User3 |  |  | 2 | Do it soon |  |

And the result:

| AssignedTo | CommentCOPY | Action | ActionNeeded | Comment | Scope |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manager | Do it now | 1 | 1 | Do it now | A |
| Manager | Do it soon | 2 | 2 | Do it soon | A |
| User2 |  |  |  | Do it soon | A |
| Manager | Do it whenever | 3 | 3 | Do it whenever | A |
| Manager | Do it now | 1 | 1 | Do it now | A |
| User3 |  |  | 2 | Do it soon |  |

Is power query capable of this kind of thing?

Comment: Can you clarify your sample data and results as they don't currently make sense

Comment: Hi! Apologies, small typo in Action column corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform multiple columns at once by using this method to do the transformations row by row.

- Change the `Source` line to reflect your actual data source.
- Note that I set the data types for the `null` columns from `any` to the possible eventual type.
- Also note that in your pasted table, what you referred to as `""` were actually `null`'s. In PQ there is a difference. Depending on what your actual data looks like, you may need to change these comparisons in the code.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table41"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"AssignedTo", type text}, {"CommentCOPY", type text}, {"Action", Int64.Type}, 
        {"ActionNeeded", Int64.Type}, {"Comment", type text}, {"Scope", type text}}),

    #"Transform Multiple Columns" = 
        Table.FromRecords(
            Table.TransformRows(#"Changed Type",
                (r) => if r[Scope] = "A" and r[ActionNeeded] <> null and r[CommentCOPY] = null 
                    then
                Record.TransformFields(
                        r,
                        {
                            {"CommentCOPY", each r[Comment]},
                            {"Action", each r[ActionNeeded]},
                            {"AssignedTo", each "Manager"}
                        }
                    )
                    else r
                ),
                Value.Type(#"Changed Type")
            )
in
    #"Transform Multiple Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution Ron.

Comment: This works really well, thank you! Just experimenting with it a bit, Is it possible to add 'then' when you have 'else r'? I have tried, but it just hangs and never loads.

Table.TransformRows(#"Changed Type",
     (r) => if ........
        then
                .....
        else if ......  
        then
                .....
        else r

Comment: @JasonRogers Yes, it is. The hanging is not due to the use of `else if ... then`